# Need Assistance with Realtime CSS Issue

Tags: css, wordpress

I am currently working on CSS design on my site [FortheStartup.com](http://www.forthestartup.com)

I am stucked at a point. The header of site is BLUE COLOR (#0d47a1) but from somewhere a white line is appearing just over the header.
I have looked around to see if there is any CSS padding etc but not able to fine.
Can anyone assist?
(I can post screenshot if required)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it comes from your #wrapper?

```
#wrapper {
 padding: 10px 0 40px;
}
```

Comment: But removing this padding from CSS in 'INSPECT ELEMENT' of Chrome doesnot affect.

Comment: Thanks. That worked :)
Actually, I was at two places in code.